# How old is the expression "to travel by [means of transportation]"?

Tags: expressions

A friend of Mari-Lou's has told her that in the old days, people traveled "on foot" or "on horseback," and the preposition "by" only entered the fray with the advent of trains and cars ("How are you getting there?" - "**By** car"). As she pondered on it, as is her commendable habit, she came to the conclusion that, *perhaps*, no one ever used the expression "***by*** **ship**" until then.

This, of course, is wrong on *so* many levels. Long-distance horseback travel was not for everybody. No woman *traveled* on horseback unless she was insane; and no man *chose* to ride for more than an hour if he could avoid it. Couriers did when the matter was urgent; a nobleman's or king's escort did spend a lot of time in the saddle, traveling *slowly*, in the wake of their employee's carriage, on the chance highway robbers might attack, or petitioners annoy, the traveler. Cowboys did, too, when they had to move cattle over long distances - again, *very slowly* (at said cattle's pace).

People who have watched way too many musketeer and/or cowboy movies should ask themselves this simple question: what do you think will happen to your buttocks *and* your groin if you spend eight to ten hours in the saddle (with no bathing facilities awaiting you at the end of the ride) and then have to do it all over the following day? And the day after that? I mean, even in Dumas' very romantic first novel of the series, it did take d'Artagnan *five days* to reach the Channel (from Paris), and he was in a hurry (and an excellent rider).

In the 15th Century, Louis XI of France established the first European post office, called *la Poste Royale*; the main post office building in New York (a.k.a. the Farley Building, built in the style of Academic Classicism) has a sign on the facade giving old Louis credit:

[image]

The expression "to travel **by** post" meant one could, for a fee, use the system to get from point A to point B, with fresh horses awaiting the harried traveler at every relay station, fed and ready to be harnessed. "*Voyage* ***par*** l*a poste*" it was called, unless I'm much mistaken.

The fabled American equivalent came a few centuries later: the Yankees and their grumpy reluctant southern compatriots traveled **by** stagecoach (average speed: 4 mph; fees: moderate; audacious highway robbers and belligerent Indians, I mean, Native Americans, everywhere).

Most European countries, from Russia to Spain, established their own versions of this system in between. People traveled **by** post.

Now comes the hard part.

"By ship," "on board ship," "by sail"? None of the above?

To be sure, the phrase "to travel by sea" (as well as its overland counterpart, "by land") was very much in use. Here's a passage from Byron's *Don Juan*:

> The approach of home to husbands and to sires,
>   After long travelling ***by land or water***,
>   Most naturally some small doubt inspires—
>   A female family 's a serious matter

And here's another one:

> She had resolved that he should travel through
>   All European climes, ***by land or sea***,
>   To mend his former morals, and get new,
>   Especially in France and Italy.

Well and good, but **did people *also* say "by ship"**? That, I'm afraid, is the question.

Comment: Eeek! No,  the user never said: *nobody ever used the expression "by ship" until then*, it was me who was wondering if that expression was ever used before the advent of motor vehicles.

Comment: The rest of the question is pretty much perfect. Thank you. **Did people before the 19th century say "travel / sail / go by ship"?**

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Poetic license. But I do see how credit should be given where credit is due. Hang on a sec.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go%20by%20ship%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1700,cd_max:1850&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: @Jim the number of hits is misleading, there are no more results beyond the second page. There are also a fair number of duplicates among the results, but there are instances of *go by ship*, which is great. Thanks.

Comment: When Jane Austen's characters took a coach, did they go "by coach"?  It is unlikely they went "on coach" or "in coach".

Comment: @ab2: I loathe Jan Austen and her characters. That said, she's probably a reliable source of popular expressions of her time. Can you recall an instance or two? I'm not doing any research that might involve reading her stuff. Well. As a matter of fact, the Bronte sisters might give us some insights. I have no quarrel with _them_.

Comment: I'm not a fan of Jane Austen either.  I thought about flipping through P&P, but suddenly felt tired.

Comment: @ab2: She might be a notch better than Ms Mitchell, which isn't saying much. I once had to travel to New Orleans to do some research for an historical novel. I didn't want to go, so I figured I'd cheat and just re-read the pertinent portion of "Gone with the Wind." Thunder and lightning. There are no streets, no buildings, no trees, no river, no cafes, no mores, no quaint expressions, and almost no people in the New Orleans part. Nothing at all to go on. Well, Austen is the same. Her alleged (sham) popularity is giving women writers a bad name.

Comment: @Mari-LouA- yeah. The examples (with dates) were why I posted it.  I didn’t even glance at the graph.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: _"Did people before the 19th century say "travel / sail / go by ship"?"_ I'm pretty sure no one said "sail by ship." What else can you sail by? Horse and buggy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gower uses it at least three times in [*Confessio Amantis*](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/Confessio/1:5?rgn=div1;view=toc) (ca. 1390):

> Fro thenne he goth toward Ytaile
> Be Schipe, and there his arivaile
> Hath take, and schop him forto ryde.  —4.93-5
>
> This king of which thou hast herde sein,
> Fro Troie as he goth hom ayein
> Be Schipe  …      — 6.1415-17
>
> And he desguised fledde awaie
> Be schipe . . . — 6.1807-8

There are also several references to letters and wheat being brought hither and thither 'by ship'.

ADDED:
I've also found a use 200 years earlier, from Layamon's [*Brut*](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=177850843&egdisplay=open&egs=177869578) (ca 1190-1215, but the citation is from an MS of about 1275)

> Ba bi londen and bi scipen, Cadwaðlan and his men ofte gunnen fusen to cumen to þissen londen.

Comment: Splendid! I'm a bit puzzled by "be" and "by," though. Were they interchangeable or something?